# set multiselect lookup column using jquery

Tags: client-object-model, jquery, lookup-column

I have a Multi select Look up column which as you all know is a control with two list boxes and "Add or Remove" Buttons.

The user populates the right-hand side of the control with some values by clicking the Add button; I have saved those selected values into array. Now the user changes an option in a cascading dropdown which actually populates this multi select lookup column.

Normally in this scenario, the default values are loaded into the left-hand side of the look up with the right-hand "Responsibility selected values" being blank. What I want to do is to load the right-hand listbox with the values stored in array.

I am open to a solution which is based on both jQuery and JavaScript Client Object Model. I haven't been successful so far. :( Please help.

```
 var newarry = new Array();
 $("[title='System']").change(function() {
     var responsibilityval = "";
     if (newarry.length > 0) {
         $.each(newarry, function(i) {
             if (newarry[i] != '') {
                 alert(newarry[i]);
                 var mySelect = $("[title='Unit']");
                 mySelect.prepend("<option value='0'>Before Apples</option>");
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

I tried other options like but it didn't work

```
var mySelect = $("[title='Unit']");
mySelect.val(1)
```

Javascript object model sample

```
 function getWebSiteData() {
     clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {

         var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
         oList = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Add New User");
         $.urlParam = function(name) {
             var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
             return results[1] || 0;
         }
         var itemid = parseInt($.urlParam('ID'));
         oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemid);
         var listinfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
         var item = oList.addItem(listinfo);
         var fields = ['Responsibility'];
         $(fields).each(function() {
             var fieldName = this;
             var field = $("#" + fieldName);
             var fieldValue = field.val();
             var entries = [];
             var newitem = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
             newitem.set_lookupId(1);

             entries.push(newitem);
             item.set_item(fieldName, entries);

         });
         item.update();
         oList.update();
         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
     }
 }

 function success(sender, args) {
     alert('success');
 }

 function failed(sender, args) {
     alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
 }
```

Comment: The fields that hold the actual value are hidden. See if this helps. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145862/jquery-appended-option-not-posting-in-default-new-form/145878#145878.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to set multi-select lookups

```
//Sets the default value(s) of a multi-select lookup
function SetMultiSelectLookup(fieldName, values)
{
    $.each(values, function(){
        $("select[title='" + fieldName + " possible values'] option:contains(" + this + ")")
                .remove()
                .appendTo($("select[title='" + fieldName + " selected values']"));
    });
    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SP OnPrem 2016 and this is working for me. The key is knowing how to set the hidden field that stores that values for the field.

**The SetMultiSelectLookup function is totally generic.**

In my case I am setting default Language Direction, so the values J>E means Japanese>English, etc. This is the Title field of my lookup list.

```
//setup default values where values = lookup id's
var defaultVals = [];
defaultVals.push(2);
defaultVals.push(3);

//call function to set multi valued lookup field
SetMultiSelectLookup('My Field Name', defaultVals);           

function SetMultiSelectLookup(fieldName, values){
        //add values to a multivalued select lookup field
        //fieldname = Title (display name) of the field
        //values = an array of lookup values, can be # or text
        try{
            var hiddenVal = '';
            //process each desired lookup value
            $.each(values, function(){
                //loop through all possible options and look for a match to the desired value
                var allOptions = $("select[title='" + fieldName + " possible values'] option");
                for (var i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {
                    var currOption = allOptions[i];
                    //in this case 'this' is the # of the lookup value we passed in
                    if(currOption.value == this){
                        //add option to the selected values field
                        $("select[title='" + fieldName + " selected values']").append(currOption);
                        //setup value for hidden field, format:
                        //  2|tJ>E
                        //  1|tE>C|t3|tE>J    //add extra '|t' between entries
                        //  2|tJ>E|t1|tE>C|t3|tE>J    //add extra '|t' between entries
                        var newVal = currOption.value + '|t' + currOption.text;
                        if(hiddenVal == ''){
                            hiddenVal = newVal;
                        } else {
                            hiddenVal = hiddenVal + '|t' + newVal;  //insert extra '|t' between entries
                        };
                    };
                };
            });

            //add to hidden field that stores the values; if we don't do this then the record won't save
            if(hiddenVal != ''){
                //the hidden field starts with the fieldname without spaces and ends with _MultiLookup
                var hiddenFieldPrefix = fieldName.replace(/ /g, '');
                $("input[id^='" + hiddenFieldPrefix + "'][id$='_MultiLookup']").val(hiddenVal);
            };
            return;
       }
       catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
       };
};
```