# jquery appended option not posting in default new form

Tags: jquery

we have a list for travel schedules.
We have a dropdown for Monday to Friday then individual mulitselects for each day.
i am trying to use the following code to auto populate the selected item for each day.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#Monday_x0020__x002d__x0020_Frida_1922e8b2-788e-47ee-a1f8-5920062dd680_\\$LookupField").change(function(){

    var fill= $('#Monday_x0020__x002d__x0020_Frida_1922e8b2-788e-47ee-a1f8-5920062dd680_\\$LookupField option:selected').val();
    alert(fill);
    var dTitle = $('#Monday_x0020__x002d__x0020_Frida_1922e8b2-788e-47ee-a1f8-5920062dd680_\\$LookupField option:selected').text();
    var dest = ('<option value="'+fill+'" title="'+dTitle+'">'+dTitle+'</option><option></option>');
$("#Monday_x0020_Travel_554556e8-f378-446a-810d-4855c469063c_SelectResult").append(dest);
$("#Tuesday_x0020_Travel_c9b9e6dc-4f15-4245-8fb0-2d115a29e003_SelectResult").append(dest);
$("#Wednesday_x0020_Travel_fa63a385-3ad5-4e22-8f8a-f3a20728d3d1_SelectResult").append(dest);
$("#Thursday_x0020_Travel_a6273f84-02a8-49d7-a35a-589cc339b99c_SelectResult").append(dest);
$("#Friday_x0020_Travel_be9b803a-bb53-4cb5-bb77-ad17b9d5c803_SelectResult").append(dest);

});
});
```

the code works for populating the "Selected Values" boxes but when I post the form the values do not post.
If I use ie dev tools and refresh the dom after auto populating the fields they show up in dev tools but still do not post.

Oddly if I add another selection to a day (as they are multiple select boxes) both values will then be posted.

I put the code into a Context Editor in the  default new form.
jquery is being loaded I just left out those calls here.

we are on SharePoint 2010

Any Ideas??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hidden fields that hold the actual value of the fields in the list.

In dev tools, `$("[id$='MultiLookup']").val()` returned the value `"2|tTest2|t3|tTest3"` for

```
<option value="2" title="Test2">Test2</option>  
<option value="3" title="Test3">Test3</option>
```

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/defaulting-values-in-a-multi-lookup-form-in-sharepoint

Comment: That was it. I just added values to that hidden field and it worked. The selected values from the auto fill now save to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a $:

```
var dest = $('<option value="'+fill+'" title="'+dTitle+'">'+dTitle+'</option><option></option>');
```

Why not clone the selected option and then append to the other selects?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Monday_x0020__x002d__x0020_Frida_1922e8b2-788e-47ee-a1f8-5920062dd680_\\$LookupField").change(function()
    {
        var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        alert(selected.val());

        $("#Monday_x0020_Travel_554556e8-f378-446a-810d-4855c469063c_SelectResult").append(selected.clone());
        $("#Tuesday_x0020_Travel_c9b9e6dc-4f15-4245-8fb0-2d115a29e003_SelectResult").append(selected.clone());
        $("#Wednesday_x0020_Travel_fa63a385-3ad5-4e22-8f8a-f3a20728d3d1_SelectResult").append(selected.clone());
        $("#Thursday_x0020_Travel_a6273f84-02a8-49d7-a35a-589cc339b99c_SelectResult").append(selected.clone());
        $("#Friday_x0020_Travel_be9b803a-bb53-4cb5-bb77-ad17b9d5c803_SelectResult").append(selected.clone());
    });
});
```

Comment: Same result. The fields are filled in but they don't post through.

Comment: When you say "posted" you mean not saved to the list, right? Anyway we could get a few screenshots to help us visual people?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `selected` attribute to the `option` element:

```
var dest = ('<option selected value="'+fill+'" title="'+dTitle+'">'+dTitle+'</option><option></option>');
```

Comment: Should have mentioned I already tried that both selected and selected="selected". Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are saying the fields are set but they don't post when saved.  That's because you need to set the related hidden field. I posted a solution here:

[set multiselect lookup column using jquery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39494/set-multiselect-lookup-column-using-jquery/266485#266485)